# How can I install a custom node version on Azure App Service for Windows

Tags: node.js, meteor, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to upgrade my Meteor app. Meteor recommends a specific version of Node to be used when deploying an app. For the [latest](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v181-2019-04-03) version of Meteor this is Node 8.15.1.

Now I checked the Kudu management app for App Service which shows all installed (Node) runtimes (`https://x.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/diagnostics/runtime`) and I'm surprised to learn that the latest installed Node 8 version is `8.11.1`, which is more then a year old (!).

How can I use the recommended version of Node (`8.15.1`) on my App Service for Windows?

I'm unable to switch to a Linux-based App Service Plan atm. If I was able to, I could use a different Docker base image.

Edit: I’ve tried setting the ‘WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION’ setting, but that only works for Node versions available on App Service

Comment: Did you get this sorted? Running into the same issue. Only 0.10.40 is installed. Setting default version does nothing. Can't deploy because devops uses kudo which uses node and getting a syntax error because 0.10.40 I don't think supports arrow functions. No pressure remembering something from 4 years ago lol

Comment: At the time I think I found no solution except for upgrading to a supported Node version. These days I’d probably use a Docker image. That way you can use whatever version you want.

Comment: Agreed. There's a wildcard I found on another answer somewhere. Basically just use `~18` or the current future version for the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` app configuration

Comment: Worth pointing out that as of 27th Feb 2024, if you specify ~18, you get 18.12.1 (circa Nov 2022), so it doesn't seem to mean you get the actual latest LTS version

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following to upgrade to latest version of Node.JS

1) package.json

put the following in your package.json

```
{
  "name": "azure_cosmos_db_webservice",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect server.js"
  },
  "engines":{"node": "8.x"}, 
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "documentdb": "^1.10.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

2) Application Setting of node js App in portal

```
Go to Application Settings, and update the value for WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION to 8.15.1
```

[image]

It should work then. Hope it helps.

Comment: The app setting you mentioned only works for Node versions that are available on App Service. Since the Node version I want is a more recent one then that’s available, that setting won’t work for me. I’ll update my question with this info, to make it more obvious.

Comment: By the way, since 8.15.1 is not available, setting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION to that value, makes App Service fall back to the oldest installed Node version, which is 0.x

Comment: Understood, yes of course it will only work till supported version which you can find it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro

Comment: The link you posted is for app service for linux containers, which has different base image version then Windows